# Unable to start the batch script when servlet context initialized

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, servlets, cmd

I am trying to start a batch script when the server start up happened using context listener.

Like below:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd /C start /B MyBat.bat );
```

The above line is in my listener class this will be invoked when server startup happened.

My problem here is I can see that above line is actually invoked because I have `sysout` next line. But the thing is its not creating batch process.

**But its invoking the batch script when I close the tomcat server(Shut down)**

I can check this process by `jconsole tool in jdk`

So I tried this way:

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd /C start  MyBat.bat );
    // I have removed /B to make window visible.
```

When I do above like this the window appeared and working fine.

But I want this `Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd /C start /B MyBat.bat );` line should execute properly.

I am running this in `Tomact 7` and `Windows server 2003`.

Please help
Thanks.

Comment: what is your bat file and locatoin

Comment: Location everything is fine.. Its not getting started on expected time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("MyBat.bat");
```

No need to give `cmd` to execute bat file in windows. Because bat file is executable in windows.

Comment: Thank you .. I dont know the process I mentioned works in my local but in server it fails.. your suggestion is working as expepcted in server.